# How can I scale my mindmap down in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, mindmaps

I am trying to scale my mindmap tikzpicture down in beamer, but I am unable to reduce the size of the circle in the middle.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=72,level distance = 25mm}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=45,level distance = 15mm}}
\tikzset{level 3 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=45,level distance = 15mm}}
\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.6}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color=blue!40, align=flush center]
    \node{Water}
    child { node {River pollution}}
    child { node {Water supply}}
    child { node {Water reuse}}
    child { node {Water conservation / demand}}
    child { node {Changing thoughts around water use}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few numbers you can play with:

1. The distance between the bubbles: change the value of `distance = 25mm`
2. To adjust the size if the bubbles: `node[scale=0.8]`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=72,level distance = 35mm}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=45,level distance = 20mm}}
\tikzset{level 3 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=45,level distance = 20mm}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color=blue!40, align=flush center]
        \node[scale=0.8]{Water}
        child { node[scale=0.8] {River pollution}}
        child { node[scale=0.8] {Water supply}}
        child { node[scale=0.8] {Water reuse}}
        child { node[scale=0.8] {Water conservation / demand}}
        child { node[scale=0.8] {Changing thoughts around water use}}
        ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The word 'Water' is too small now. How do I change the font size?

Comment: @ahorn `\Huge Water`?

Comment: Yes, that worked.